# How to hide EditText search when scroll up ListView android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Im using ToolBar, EditText Search and ListView, I want when scroll up listview, EditText Search will hide and when scroll down EditText Search show (Only EditText is show or hide, not ToolBar). I have tried and searched a lot of ways but I have not found answer for this. I just find for ToolBar.

This my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.totoroads.android.app.ListViewBottomSheetActivity"
android:background="@color/backgroundColorGray">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/bg_search_map"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Enter Place Here"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gosearch"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:text="TÌM" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="LỌC" />

</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteEditText" />

<!-- Bottom Bar No Navigation -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchMapButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/search_list_map" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/otherSearchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/search_nearby" />
</LinearLayout>
<!-- Ending Botton Bar -->
```

Within ToolBar is above and EditText Search is below

How to hide EditText search when scroll up ListView ? Thank so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/profile_tablayout_indicator_height"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_beats"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

try urls:

https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/

http://mobikul.com/hideshow-toolbar-scrolling/

Comment: Thank for your reply, but I don't use scroll up or down for ToolBar, I want to keep ToolBar, just for EditText Search

Comment: @ThanhNamPham You can modify this according to you.

Comment: Okey, I will try and back.. :)

Comment: @ThanhNamPham Glad to hear you found your answer!!